# L1 functions on a compact domain bounded almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $f\in L^1(K)$ where $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ is compact. Then $f$ is bounded almost everywhere.

I'm pretty sure this is true, it seems true, but I didn't see it in my notes/book and so I wanted to be sure I'm not missing something after a long day. Here's my proof:

There exist a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ converging uniformly to $f$ (since continuous functions are dense in $L^1$). Thus, $\exists N:|f_N(x)-f(x)|<1$ for almost all $x\in K$. So $1-f_N(x)<f(x)<1+f_N(x)$. But $f_N$ is continuous on $K$ so $\exists M>0$ such that $f_N(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in K$. Thus, for almost all $x\in K$, we have $1-M<f(x)<1+M$ as desired.

Comment: The continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ but using the $L^1$ norm. If a sequence of continuous functions converges to $f$ uniformly, then $f$ is also continuous (and hence bounded).

Comment: Continuous functions are dense in $\mathbf{L}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ means that they are dense with respect to the norm of the normed space $\mathbf{L}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$, not with the norm of other space (the norm of $\mathbf{L}^\infty_{\mathbb{R}}$ is the one for uniform convergence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true, take $K=[0,1]$ and $f(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{x}}$. Then
$\|f\|_1 = 2$, but for any $B>0$, we see that
$m \{ x | |f(x)| >B \} = m (0,{1 \over B^2}) = {1 \over B^2} >0$.

What is true is that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $A \subset K$ and $B>0$ such that $m A < \epsilon$ and $|f(x)| \le B$ for $x \notin A$.

Answer (score 1):

The example given above here is great. I believe that the closest we can get is that $f \in L^1(K)$ implies that there exists a sequence of continuous functions $\{C_k\}$ such that $C_k \overset{L^1}{\to} f$, i.e.,

$$\int_K |f-C_k| \to 0. $$

Unfortunately, this doesn't tell us about convergence on other topologies.